# Alpha AXP シミュレーターの "Crude mp" がビルドできない

Tags: c++

[Alpha Axp シミュレーター](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~oskin/Bliss/)の Crude MP をビルド出来ません。Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bit) に 32bit 環境を整え、`g++` にも `-m32` をつけています。`Stack.h` の `GetSize` も `Array<T>::GetSize` にしました。以下は端末の出力です。

```
Simulators/run-alpha.o:run-alpha.cxx:(.text+0x169): `Allocator<Instruction>::ObjectStack' に対する定義されていない参照がさらに続いています
Simulators/run-alpha.o: 関数 `runtest(char*, char**)' 内:
run-alpha.cxx:(.text+0x239): `operator new[](unsigned int)' に対する定義されていない参照です
run-alpha.cxx:(.text+0x23f): `Allocator<Instruction>::ObjectStack' に対する定義されていない参照です
（以下続く）
```

個人的には`Allocator.h`の

```cpp
#   define  DEFINE_ALLOCATOR(TTT) template<class TTT> Stack<TTT *> Allocator<TTT>::ObjectStack
```

に原因があると思うのですが、テンプレートにマクロを使うのはまずいのでしょうか。
いい考えがあったら、教えてください。お願いします。

Comment: 自己フォローです。run-alpha.cxxの前半にDEFINE_ALLOCATOR(TTT)を書き込んで、-m32を外してmakeしたらうまくいきました。お騒がせしてすみませんでした。

Comment: sunaoさん、時間が経ってしまいましたが、スタック・オーバーフローでは自分で解決できた場合[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)することができ、また推奨されています。投稿から少し時間をおけばその自己回答を承認することもできますので、もしよければご検討ください :)